# Why do Images take forever to load?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, pagespeed

WordPress website hosted on AWS EC2 t2.micro (LAMP).

The website page load time is around 1-2 secs.

However, I always have a selection of images that take 6-10 seconds to load.

It is not always the same image that takes a long time to load.

When I check page speed on GT Metrix I get varying results as to which images are loading slowly. (See below - 2 separate GT Metrix tests with different results)

If the images are served from a CDN they still take a long time to load (6-10 secs)

The images are compressed and have a small file size.

1. Is this a server issue and if so how do I fix?
2. If not, any ideas?

[image: GTMetrix test 1]
[image: GTMetrix test 2]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your files to the JPEG format, and then if it is still not the fastest you could try compressing the files down, until you have a good compromise of image quality, and page speed/image size.